# express auth middleware returning "Not authorized" error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, mern

I have an auth protect middleware that checks if req.params.id === req.userId(the one returned by bcrypt verify function). I have a protect function which upon bcrypt.verify returns the decoded.id.

The Id returned from req.user._id despite being the same as decoded.id returns "not authorized in the verifyandAuth middleware, however, if I replace req.user._id by decoded.id(in verifyandAuth), the if function works and the middleware goes through without giving the "not authorized error". Can anybody please tell me why that's happening? (req.user._id and decoded.id upon console.log show the same id, as such, there's no mistake there).

Protect Middleware

```
export const protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  )
    try {
      {
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "kris");
        req.userId = decoded.id;
        req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
        next();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json(error.message);
    }

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(400).json("Invalid Token");
  }
};
```

auth Middleware

```
export const verifyandAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  protect(req, res, () => {
    console.log(req.user._id, req.params.id);

    if (req.user._id === req.params.id || req.isAdmin) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(400).json("Not authorised");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you sure `req.user._id` is a string and not an ObjectId? Otherwise your strict comparison (`===`) with `req.params.id` will fail.

Comment: Ah, yes that might be the problem. Can you please tell me how to convert the objectId into string(and vice versa) so that the whole thing passes the === operator. And also, thanks a TON!

Comment: If that's the problem, using `==` should work. If you want to use strict comparison, you can use `req.user._id.toString()` or `String(req.user._id)`.